# How can I checkin a file, generated by maven build, automatically in SVN?

Tags: java, svn, maven, build, jenkins

I build my project in Jenkins and during the build process I generate some DB files.

They should be checked in SVN at the end.

How can I do that?

Comment: If your build produces these DB files, and your source code is in source control, why do you want to check-in the generated files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the maven-scm-plugin. Especially the goal checkin:

http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkin-mojo.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ant` there is `<svn>` task defined already you can use them

Quick finding http://imwill.com/svntask-examples-for-apache-ant/#.UFHKho3ibpo

Maven provides `SCM` plugin to work with several source version control systems. You can look into them once.